# Having Recursion error while creating .exe file of my Tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, executable

I've written a code in tkinter (Python). I've different files and I combined these files in a main file with subprocess (connect different files with corresponding buttons in main file).
The whole code is working well and running exactly as I'm expecting, but while converting the app into .exe file (using pyinstaller), i'm facing "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a python object".
How can I convert my .py file to .exe ?

Here is my main.py file code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import subprocess

class PlayerExApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Player Ex | Media Player")
        master.geometry("1280x720")  # Set an initial window size

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Create a Frame for the root window
        root_frame = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding="10", style="White.TFrame")
        root_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Create a Frame for the left side
        left_frame = ttk.Frame(root_frame, style="White.TFrame")
        left_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=False, padx=(75, 75))

        # Create a Label for the "PlayerEx" heading
        heading_label = ttk.Label(left_frame, text="Media", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"), style="Black.TLabel")
        heading_label.pack(pady=(50, 20))

        # Create buttons for the left side
        left_buttons = ttk.Frame(left_frame, style="White.TFrame")
        left_buttons.pack()

        for text, command in [("Audio Player", "audio-player.py"),
                              ("Video Player", "video-player.py")]:
            button = ttk.Button(left_buttons, text=text, style="Grey.TButton",
                                command=lambda c=command: self.on_button_press(c))
            button.pack(ipadx=90, pady=(0, 10))

        # Create a label for the Features heading
        heading_label = ttk.Label(left_frame, text="Features", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"), style="Black.TLabel")
        heading_label.pack(pady=(50, 20))

        # Create buttons for the left side
        left_buttons = ttk.Frame(left_frame, style="White.TFrame")
        left_buttons.pack()

        for text, command in [("Audio Clipper", "audio-clipper.py"),
                              ("MP3 Converter", "video-converter.py"),
                              ("Extract Vocals", "root.py"),
                              ("Enhance Video", "enhance-video.py")]:
            button = ttk.Button(left_buttons, text=text, style="Grey.TButton",
                                command=lambda c=command: self.on_button_press(c))
            button.pack(ipadx=90, pady=(0, 10))

        # Create a Frame for the right side
        right_frame = ttk.Frame(root_frame, style="Black.TFrame")
        right_frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Create an Image for the logo
        logo_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="images/logo.png")
        # Resize the logo image
        logo_img = logo_img.subsample(2)  # Reduce the size by a factor of 2
        logo_label = ttk.Label(right_frame, image=logo_img)
        logo_label.image = logo_img
        logo_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=300, expand=False)

        # Make the window responsive
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        left_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        right_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def on_button_press(self, command):
        print(f"Button pressed for command: {command}")
        subprocess.run(["python", command])

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = PlayerExApp(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You will need to show us the actual traceback too, not just the error message.

Comment: what is the filename of your application?

Comment: Here is the Traceback :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RAS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1084, in emit
    stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Post the full traceback in the question, not in comment.  Also the traceback error is not related to recursion error mentioned in the question title.